# Texts Overlap in Tabs with Previous Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs

I am developing an Android App. After navigating some screen in my Android Application when I press on back button Texts Overlap in Tabs with previous.

Screen shot is below:

[image]

I didn't get the reason.

Please help with any clue.

Comment: Can you please post some code ?

Comment: Add code of tabs lyaout

Comment: I used left navigation Drawer with some tabs. I did not find the any specific code to share for this problem.